# Regular Expression to get parts of the string which are not inside of $( )

Tags: java, regex

Can you please help me out to write a regular expression for the below string,

`Hi $(abc) frnd $(xyz)`

In this text I want to match all words that are not surrounded by `$( )`.So, in the above string I want to match `Hi` and `frnd`

I tried with `\$((.[^)]*.))` but it matches $(abc) and $(xyz). But I want to match the ones outside the symbols

Comment: I am trying in java. I tried with \$((.[^)]*.)) but this gets matched with $(abc) $(xyz). But I want the inversion.

Comment: @Lenymm - I'm not sure its a duplicate.

Comment: Actualy no. I think it is the right answer.

Comment: You could replacing \$(.+) with an empty string

Answer (score 1):

Can you use negative lookbehind in Java? This seems to work in C# (but you never can tell 100% with regexes!)

```
(?<!\$\([A-Za-z]*)[A-Za-z]+(?!\))
```

Comment: Java supports negative look-behind, but not variable width like C#. Your regex will not compile in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can either split the string into parts that don't contain `$(...)`, or you can use `replaceAll` function to remove the `$(...)`.

```
// Raw regex: \$\([^)]+\)

str.split("\\$\\([^)]+\\)");

str.replaceAll("\\$\\([^)]+\\)", "")
```

Then you can extract text all you want. The regex assumes that the text in between `$(...)` doesn't allow `)` to be specified. In cases such as `$(abc$(crap)_outside`, only `_outside` will be left after the replacement.

It is possible to write a single regex to pick out the words and ignore the `$(...)`, by using last match boundary `\G`, but it is simpler to do as above: remove the `$(...)` parts before matching the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code It will print desired output.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String text = "Hi $(abc) frnd $(xyz)";
    String[] textArr = text.split("\\$\\([^)]*\\)");

    for (String word : textArr)
    {
        System.out.println(word.trim());

    }

}
```